# Data check on SQL insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data with the following sample data:

```
ID  CID     Name            ImageLocation                           Order   
1   1   Suit Jacket Content/Berwin/Content/Images/SuitJacket.jpg    1
2   1   Trousers    Content/Berwin/Content/Images/Trousers.jpg      2
4   2   Jumper      Content/Berwin/Content/Images/Jumper.jpg        1
5   3   Trousers    Content/Berwin/Content/Images/Trousers.jpg      1
6   4   Suit Jacket Content/Berwin/Content/Images/SuitJacket.jpg    1
```

**ID is PK, CID is FK and order is the order to be shown in not an Order FK**

Is there anyway to enforce that the number within the `Order` column is unique within the scope of its `CID`. I.e. I wouldn't be able to insert `1 or 2` when `CID is 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can add a new 'Unique Key' to your database.

- In SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Design mode of your table.
- Right-click > Indexes/Keys...
- Add a new Index/Key
- Set its type as "Unique Key"
- Add Columns `CID` and `Order`
- Close dialog window and save table

Answer (score 2):

If you have that sample data in your table, and you don't want to be able to insert another row where CID = 1 and order = 1 or 2, then you can do this by adding a unique index to those columns.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_CID_ORDER ON dbo.TABLE
    (
    CID,
    Order
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

...or you can add a unique constraint across two columns

```
ADD CONSTRAINT CID_Order_Const UNIQUE(CID, Order)
```

Comment: Good point to only add a constraint and not an index, though the index can be beneficial in other ways.

Comment: @cairnz - no such thing really - a unique constraint in SQL Server is *implemented* as a unique index.

Comment: Yep, its purely syntactic sugar